# Loading whats inside of an "div" ajax jquery .load()?

Tags: jquery, html, load

I want to load the content(whats inside) of a DIV **not** the div itselfe?

the index.php:

```
$('header.teaserimage').load('gallery-uln8.php '+$ancor);
```

Structure of: gallery-uln8.php:

```
<div id="pic00">
   <img src="... ...>
</div>
...
<div id="picXX">
   <img src="... ...>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this with the .load()- method of jQuery or should I use somwthing elese?

Comment: Can you re-word this. It is confusing.

Comment: What?  not sure what you are asking here

Comment: I think what shes asking is how can she load in the HTML from gallery-uln8.php but without the div tags - she just wants the img tags.

Comment: still a bit vague in the html shown what is being searched for since `$anchor` isn't defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following assumes that `$anchor` is a valid selector. load() is a shortcut ajax method as is $.get. They both pull in all that is output from the url. $.get just gives you a bit more flexibility

```
$.get('gallery-uln8.php', function(data){
    $('header.teaserimage').html( $(data).find($ancor).html())

});
```

Comment: ..i like this method but if i do `alert($(data).find($ancor).html());` it parses "null" I get $anchor via: `$ancor = $(this).attr('href');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get('gallery-uln8.php ' + $ancor, null, function(data){
    $('header.teaserimage').empty();
    $("img ", $(data)).each(function(){
        $('header.teaserimage').append(this);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to load the content in a temporary div and then use
`$('header.teaserimage').html($('#temp-div').find($anchor).html());`

Answer (score 0):

Your load function will load whatever is output from the gallery-uln-8.php script, so the simplest way would be to edit that page and remove the divs.

Alternatively, you could parse the loaded content from the gallery-uln8.php in jQuery and remove the divs - but that would introduce a lot of complexity to your code and I wouldn't recommend that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
$('header.teaserimage').load('gallery-uln8.php #pic00 img');
```